# Cannot read property 'linkButton' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jsf, icefaces

I am using JSF in my application. I am getting runtime error while displaying data through ace linkButton.

Error i am getting is : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'linkButton' of undefined

Due to this link is not enable. I understand something is not initialize that is why i am getting error, but dont know what.

This is my Code:

```
<ice:panelGroup>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Downstream info</legend>
        <ice:panelGrid columns="2">
            <ice:outputLabel value="Channel type" />
            <ice:outputText value="Primary"/>

            <!-- Downstream -->
            <ice:outputLabel value="Channel ID" />
            <ice:panelSeries id="dsChannelId" value="#{viewCustomerBean.pollModemResult.downstreamChannelID}" var="item">
                <ice:panelGroup style="width:63px;float:left;text-align:center;"><ice:outputText value="#{item}" /></ice:panelGroup>
            </ice:panelSeries>              

            <ice:outputLabel value="Frekvens (Hz)" />
            <ice:panelSeries id="dsFrekvensId" value="#{viewCustomerBean.pollModemResult.downstreamFrekvens}" var="item">
                <ice:panelGroup style="width:63px;float:left;text-align:right;"><ice:outputText value="#{item}" rendered="#{item!=0}"/></ice:panelGroup>
                <ace:linkButton id="FrekID" value="#{item}" action="#{viewCustomerBean.pollModemResult.showFreqPopup}" rendered="#{item==0}"/>
            </ice:panelSeries>              

            <ice:outputLabel value="Received power level  (dBuV)" />
            <ice:panelSeries id="dsPowerId" value="#{viewCustomerBean.pollModemResult.downstreamReceivedPowerLevel}" var="item">
                <ice:panelGroup style="width:63px;float:left;text-align:center;"><ice:outputText value="#{item}" /></ice:panelGroup>
            </ice:panelSeries>              

            <ice:outputLabel value="Downstream SNR  (dB)" />
            <ice:panelSeries id="dsSNRId" value="#{viewCustomerBean.pollModemResult.downstreamSNR}" var="item">
                <ice:panelGroup style="width:63px;float:left;text-align:center;"><ice:outputText value="#{item}" /></ice:panelGroup>
            </ice:panelSeries>              

            <ice:outputLabel value="Downstream MER  (dB)" />
            <ice:panelSeries id="dsMERId" value="#{viewCustomerBean.pollModemResult.downstreamMER}" var="item">
                <ice:panelGroup style="width:63px;float:left;text-align:center;"><ice:outputText value="#{item}" /></ice:panelGroup>
            </ice:panelSeries>              

        </ice:panelGrid>
    </fieldset>
</ice:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Hi, please create a [mcve]. Highest chance is that you manually included a jquery library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `<ace:linkButton>` to `<ice:commandLink>` and now it is working, although I still don't know what was the issue.